# Идентификация светодиодов на VR шлеме

Tags: c++, opencv

Стоит задача, разработать алгоритм идентификации светодиодов гарнитуры VR шлема по стереоизображениям. На вход подаётся два изображения с левой и правой камер.
Уже реализован алгоритм поиска соответствующих пар светодиодов на изображениях стереопары.
Помимо изображений, на вход подаются координаты светодиодов в системе координат самого шлема и кватернионы поворота от инерциального датчика шлема.

Хоть как-то подступиться к этой задаче идентификации, я преобразую координаты светодиодов из 3D в 2D и отображаю на изображении. Каждый цвет круга обозначает определённый светодиод (фронтальный левый нижний/верхний и тд).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так это сейчас выгладит.

Только как теперь идентифицировать светодиоды на изображении? На данном изображении результат должен быть следующим: желтый, красный, белый, зелёный, серый (отсчёт против часовой стрелке, начинается от верхнего левого светодиода)

Comment: Так стоп, у вас все светодиоды одного цвета? А управлять их свечением вы можете?

Comment: @gbg, да, светодиоды все одного цвета. Нет, управлять свечением не могу

Comment: Я бы все же рассмотрел возможность сделать включение светодиодов управляемым. Без этого придется восстанавиливать по параллаксам 3d координаты точек (и тут есть риск криво смэтчить), а потом решать систему линейных уравнений.

Comment: @gbg, можете, пожалуйста, поподробнее пояснить, что значит "восстановить по параллаксам"? Это будет разница светодиода положения светодиода на левом и правом изображениях?

Comment: Ну, есть разные алгоритмы решения данной задачи - зависит от того, какая у вас конечная цель. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008548/opencv-3d-from-points-in-stereo-pair

Comment: @gbg, текущая цель это идентифицировать светодиоды на изображении

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135023/discussion-between-gbg-and-loki).